# Saving my 'bacon'

Tags: pork

I bought one of these recently, smoked shoulder or something like that.

Given that it 'looked cooked', I just sliced it and figured we could eat it cold. But it didn't look particularly cooked inside, and was awful chewy.

So, I think I've screwed up. Given that it is now in slices, what can I do to avoid throwing it away (or having to eat it all myself because the rest of the family refuses to!)?

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of the slices?  To me the item pictured might be raw but covered with a smoked paprika rub or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a a fully cooked, cured ham.

These are salt cured, and so will have a pinker appearance, but are ready to eat.  They are perfectly safe despite the color.

Many people enjoy them better sliced thinly, so that they are not as chewy.

---

You can use the slice in sandwiches, or chop them as an add-in to soups.  You can just heat them up eat them as (I like them with mashed potatoes).  Ham is extremely flexible.

Comment: Yes, well it did look cooked to me, as I said, but the extreme chewiness made me doubt. Maybe I just had bad luck and got a low quality chewy pig :(

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, checking on the internet, it even said that it needed cooking on the packaging, I just didn't think to look.

In the end, I was saved by my Romertopf. After an hour and a half in their, the slices came out non-chewy, not dry, (and still ridiculously salty). Success!

[image]

Comment: If its too salty, its worth soaking in fresh water overnight. Or one of the other methods for removing excess salt.

Comment: @NBenatar. Yes I made the mistake of thinking 'oh, juice!' when I finished cooking it, and using it to make the accompanying couscous. Eating it was... an experience.

Comment: Oops. Well at least you wont make the same mistake twice.